# Using the React Children code example is not working

Tags: reactjs, children

"Using the React Children API" code example is not working, tried several syntax options, seems the problem is not quite clear.

http://developingthoughts.co.uk/using-the-react-children-api/

```
class TabContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.state = {
            currentTabName: props.defaultTab
        }
    }

    setActiveChild = (currentTabName) => {
        this.setState({ currentTabName });
    }

    renderTabMenu = (children) => {
        return React.Children.map(children, child => (
            <TabMenuItem 
                title={child.props.title}
                onClick={() => this.setActiveChild(child.props.name)}
            />
        );
    }

    render() {
        const { children } = this.props;
        const { currentTabName } = this.state;

        const currentTab = React.Children.toArray(children).filter(child => child.props.name === currentTabName);

        return (
            <div>
                {this.renderTabMenu(children)}
                <div>
                    {currentTab}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

When I changed code like this, it compiles finally

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";

const TabMenuItem = ({ title, onClick }) => (
    <div onClick={onClick}>
        {title}
    </div>
);

class TabContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      currentTabName: props.defaultTab
    }
  }

  setActiveChild = ( currentTabName ) => {
    this.setState({ currentTabName });
  }

  renderTabMenu = ( children ) => {
    return React.Children.map(children, child => (
      <TabMenuItem 
      title={child.props.title}
      onClick={() => this.setActiveChild(child.props.name)}
      />
      ))
  }

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;
    const { currentTabName } = this.state;

    const currentTab = React.Children.toArray(children).filter(child =>
      child.props.name === currentTabName);

    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderTabMenu(children)}
        <div>
          {currentTab}
        </div>
      </div>
      );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TabContainer />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Not quite experienced with JS and React, so my questions:

1) should this.setActiveChild be used as this.props.setActiveChild?

2) renderTabMenu = ( children ) or renderTabMenu = ({ children })

3) how to fill this page with some content? I don't see any physical children actually present =)

4) don't get the point why bloggers put the code with errors or which is difficult to implement, very frustrating for newcomers

5) any general guidance what can be not working in this example are welcome

Comment: What error message do you get? And how are you implementing TabContainer in the rest of your code?

Comment: Basically the code is not mine, just trying to implement example code into some working example. I'll read some more reliable examples and figure out how it can be used..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `React.Children` or `this.props.children` can be a bit of a level up in your understanding of React and how it works. It'll take a few tries in making a component work but you'll get that aha moment at some point. In a nutshell.

> **this.props.children** is an array of `<Components />` or html tags at the top level.

For example:

```
<MyComponent>
  <h1>The title</h1>         // 1st child
  <header>                   // 2nd child
    <p>paragraph</p>
  </header>
   <p>next parapgraph</p>    // 3rd child
</MyComponent>
```

**1) should this.setActiveChild be used as this.props.setActiveChild?**
Within the `TabContainer` any functions specified within it need to be proceeded with `this`. Within a react class `this` refers to the class itself, in this case, `TabContainer`. So using `this.setActiveChild()`. will call the function within the class. If you don't specify `this` it will try to look for the function outside of the class.

**renderTabMenu = ( children ) or renderTabMenu = ({ children })**
`renderTabMenu` is a function which accepts one param `children`, so call it as you would call it as a normal function `renderTabMenu(childeren)`

**How to fill this page with some content? I don't see any physical children actually present =)**
Here's where the power of the TabsContainer comes in. Under the hood, things like conditional rendering happen but outside of it in another component you specify the content. Use the following structure to render home, blog, and contact us tabs.

```
<TabsContainer defaultTab="home">
  <Tab name="home" title="Home">
    Home Content
  </Tab>
  <Tab name="blog" title="Blog">
    Blog Content
  </Tab>
  <Tab name="contact" title="Contact Us">
    Contact content
  </Tab>
</TabsContainer>
```

I know how hard it is to make some examples work especially when you are starting out and are still exploring different concepts that react has to offer. Luckily there's stack overflow :).

Here's real live example to play around with, visit [this CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/2zlo9j3x6n).

Comment: Thanks for the very useful working example. Reading [ReactJS Tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) also clarified on how to use React.Component class and its difference from functions approach. But, still even little mistakes may render the code unusable. I personally edit in Sublime 3 and render in a browser in case I forgot to put some brackets =) or the source code is somehow unusable.

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to update this answer as the accepted one so anyone visiting this later knows we got a solution for this.